# Perl built-ins to find list of indices pointing to unique entries in a list

Tags: perl, built-in

Say I have a list of strings with possible repetitions. I am trying to find the list of sorted indices of this list that hold the unique entries in the list of strings.

E.g. Given:

```
my @string_list = ("hello", "world", "hello", "how", "are", "world");
```

The output with the list of indices would be: `[0, 1, 3, 4]` which correspond to the words `"hello"`, `"world"`, `"how"` and `"are"`.

To do this, I can loop through the input list and keep track of the elements I have seen in a list in a dictionary that hold these indices, and use these indices later to obtain a list of unique items.

However, I was wondering if there are any other built-ins, functions or data-structures in Perl that facilitate this task and maybe avoid writing this in a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in for such a concept as it isn't a very general thing to want to do. However it is only a couple of lines of code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @string_list = qw( hello world hello how are world );

my @indices = do {
  my %seen;
  map { $seen{$string_list[$_]}++ ? () : ($_) } 0 .. $#string_list;
};

printf "[%s]\n", join ', ', @indices;
```

**output**

```
[0, 1, 3, 4]
```